# How to change a string to utf8 encoded?

Tags: php, encoding

I want to make a string to `utf8` encoded, but I don't know what the original charset it is.

The original charset of string may be `GBK`, `iso-8859-1`, or others I don't know.

I use `mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', true)` and `iconv($original, "UTF-8", $content);`

How to get the original encoding ?

Comment: Have you read [the `mb_detect_encoding()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)? `mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', true)` makes no sense.

Comment: Then did you try ` mb_detect_encoding($content, 'auto', true)`. Be warned that there may be no save way to detect your encodings correctly in every case, because it's more like a process of guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is maybe useful http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php